# Godaddy, EC2, Route53. and Hosted email

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-route53

I have the following setup

1. Godaddy domain name
2. AWS EC2 server host
3. AWS Route53 IP management

I have the nameserver options on godaddy pointing towards the 4 nameservers given by Route53 which are in turn linked to my EC2 instance, this setup all seems to be working correctly and when I type www.foo.com I end up on my website.

I have just purchased email from godaddy which I now need to varify that I own foo.com, I have followed the guide "Set mail destination for foo.com"

```
 1. Log in to your account at the other company.
 2. TXT Record: Find where to add a TXT record, and enter
Name    TXT Value
@   MS=345678654
@   v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all

 3. CNAME Records: Find where to add a CNAME record, and enter
Host    Points to
autodiscover    autodiscover.outlook.com
sip sipdir.online.lync.com
lyncdiscover    webdir.online.lync.com
email   email.secureserver.net
msoid   clientconfig.microsoftonline-p.net

 4. MX Records: Find where to add an MX record, and enter
Host    Priority    Target
@   0   foo-com.mail.protection.outlook.com

 5. SRV Records: Find where to add an SRV record, and enter
Port    Protocol    Name    Service Priority    Weight  Target
443 _tls    @   _sip    100 1   sipdir.online.lync.com
5061    _tcp    @   _sipfederationtls   100 1   sipfed.online.lync.com
```

I am on the foo.com hosted zone in route53, which I have tried to copy the values from above into, I now have 12 records

- 1x A, 6x CNAME, 1x MX, 1x NS, 1x SOA, 1x SRV, 1x TXT

Which has ended up looking like this
B5wB1YJ.png on imgur will show you a what my setup looks like

When I click the check button on godaddy I am presented with the following

> Sorry, we can't verify your settings, yet. It can take up to 1 hour for us to detect the update. Please double-check you entered the information correctly, and try again in a bit.

It's been 3 hours, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check if your DNS settings are updated using https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3agoogle.com&run=toolpage# sometime it can be delayed.

Comment: Thanks, that's throwing a few errors
 `Category Host Result 

 spf foo.com DNS Record not found

 dmarc foo.com DNS Record not found
 
smtp foo.com.mail.protection.outlook.com Failed To Connect
 
smtp foo.com.mail.protection.outlook.com IP Resolution Error

 mx foo.com No DMARC Record found
 
dns foo.com SOA Serial Number Format is Invalid`

Cannot figure out how to do linebreaks....

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm stuck in the same spot